# Detect when user stops touching UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton which has a UIPanGesture attached to it. When the user press down on the UIButton, I call the event `Touch Down`. I also want to figure out when the user lifts his or her finger up from the button, after having possibily dragged it around the screen. I've tried using the delegates such as `Touch Up Inside` or `Touch Drag Exit` but these don't seem to work after the UIButton has been dragged around...

Comment: try UIControlEventTouchCancel

Comment: @user3705414 unfortunately whenever the user begins dragging it calls UIControlEventTouchCancel, and I want it to be called on lifting of the finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fire only if the pan gesture recognizer begins. It will not fire if the user merely taps the button.

```
-(void)setupGesture
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [self.yourButton addGestureRecognizer:pan];
 }


-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            //Should fire when the user lifts finger
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```